# Running docker containers with .net6

Tags: c#, .net, docker, .net-core, dockerfile

I'm currently building an example of an API by using .net6 and I'm tracking to use docker to run the API.

My docker file looks like this:

```
# Grab the app package and create a new build
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build-env
# Let's add all the files into the app directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy everything
COPY . ./
# Restore as distinct layers
RUN dotnet restore
# Build and publish a release
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DotNet.Docker.dll"]
```

I created the image by running this command:

```
 docker build -t binarythistle/dockerapi .
```

Now, I'm trying to run the image to create the container:

```
docker run -p 8000:80 dockerapi
```

But, I'm getting the following result:

```
The command could not be loaded, possibly because:
  * You intended to execute a .NET application:
      The application 'DotNet.Docker.dll' does not exist.
  * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
      No .NET SDKs were found.

Download a .NET SDK:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

Learn about SDK resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/sdk-not-found
```

Does anyone has any idea what can be done to solve this issue?

Site Note: I downloaded the .NET6.0 SDK macOS as recommended but I'm still having an issue. The project that I'm running with .net is a standard api project where the command that allowed me to create this is the following:

```
dotnet new webapi -n DockerAPI
```

Answer (score 3):

I was also facing the same issue, however, it got it fixed after replacing below line in the docker file.

Old:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DotNet.Docker.dll"]
```

New:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SampleWebApplication.dll"]
```

Use *your_application_name.dll* in place of *SampleWebApplication.dll*.

Answer (score 2):

There's no `DotNet.Docker.dll` within that directory that you're running `dotnet`.

The best way to solve this is to shell in to the container you've just created

```
docker run -it dockerapi bash
```

`-it` will make it an interactive processes
`bash` will change the ENTRYPOINT to be `bash`

once you've got a shell then run an `ls` command and see what files have been copied from the previous layer in the docker build

```
ls
```

Answer (score 1):

try running like this

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "./DotNet.Docker" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I messed up the folder path.

I bind a volume to the default path `/app`.

This volume obviously doesn't contain any .dll file, so .NET cannot run, thus the message: `The application '*.dll' does not exist.`